# eddystone url not working with url that redirect

Tags: eddystone, eddystone-url

This behaviour seems pretty consistent, but I cannot find any documentation from google (or anyone else) that would say that this is the case, and what are ways to deal with this issue.

Is it possible to use redirection/url-shorteners with eddystone-url?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*after some trial and error...*

Found out the requirement I was missing was that the links I was using did not have meta tags.

I was able to use my https re-director to forward to the google website. Then I changed the redirection to a different link, but that no longer works, it only forwards to google. I've removed all links, so there's no way it could redirect at all now, but chrome-pw and the physical-web app still shows the google website.

Some time later, I set another url and it worked again, but a subsequent change would not be reflected.

It looks like google knows that it's using a redirection service and resolves the link. It also caches it, so subsequent changes do not go through.

Comment: The idea of the Proxy Web service is to cache. Changes will go through but they are not immediate. If you have control of the web server and it uses a Cache-Control header, make sure you set it to at least 24 hours so that it gives the Google Physical Web Proxy time to update it while using the old cached version.

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of ways in which triggering might not work including no connectivity, not using SSL and slow shortener. Here's a [comprehensive troubleshooting guide](https://www.beaconzone.co.uk/blog/troubleshooting-eddystone-url-on-android/).

Comment: I can't get past step 2 :(  the url provided as example does not show up through the chrome app's physical web

Comment: Please give the URL for me to try

Comment: I was trying to use the one in the article, `http://bzone.click/bz` which passes this validator `https://beaufortfrancois.github.io/sandbox/physical-web/url-validator/`

Comment: I've also set up `goo.gl/ZbWwBv` to redirect to `google.ca`, but oppon checking it with https://beaufortfrancois.github.io/sandbox/physical-web/url-validator/ it fails

Comment: Google might be blocking Physical Web redirects to their own sites. Try using your own (SSL) URL.

Answer (score 0):

Url shorteners are almost always used with Eddystone-URL, and I have commonly used them with success.  So I suspect something else may be the issue.

If using Nearby or Chrome to do the detection, you must make sure that the URL can actually be resolved to a website, and that there is not robots.txt in the root of the site that prevents crawling the pages.  Google needs to crawl the pages to give a title and summary of the page associated with the URL.